# Return a std string in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to return the `string rock` in my function. I call the function by using `cout<<computertest.returncomputer()<<endl;` in main function. However I got a empty string. But if I change rock to "abc", it will return abc. What am I doing wrong in my code? By the way, test1 and test2 give me R R R R when size = 7.

```
//computer.cpp
#include "computer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
Computer::Computer(string Rock, int Size){
    rock = Rock;
    size = Size;
}
void Computer::Computerplayer(){

    int i = 0;
    int l = 1;

    for(i=0;i<size;i+=2){

        rock += 'R';
        rock += ' ';

    }
    /*cout<<"test1 "<<rock<<endl;*/

}

string Computer::returncomputer(){
  /* cout<<"test2 "<<rock<<endl; */
    return rock;
}
```

header

```
//computer.h
#ifndef COMPUTER_H
#define COMPUTER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Computer{
    public:
    Computer(string Rock, int Size);
    void Computerplayer();
    string returncomputer();
    private:
    string rock;
    int size;




};
#endif
```

main

```
//main.cpp
#include "computer.h"
#include "human.h"
#include "referee.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

int main(){

    int size;
    string type = "3 S R P";
    string rock;
    getline(cin, type);
    size = type.length();

    cout<< size<<endl;
    Human humantest(size, type);
    Computer computertest(rock, size);
    /*Referee refereetest(size, type, computertest.returncomputer());
    humantest.Humanplayer();
    refereetest.Result();*/
    /*computertest.Computerplayer();*/
    cout<<computertest.returncomputer()<<endl;


}
```

Comment: The code looks fine.  Please provide a [mcve] including the declaration of the `Computer` class, and the code that is using the class. In the code shown, the only way a blank string can be returned from `returncomputer()` is if `rock` is blank to begin with, which would imply that the `computertest` variable is not being initialized properly.

Comment: You should hard-code the data into your program instead of input statements.  That way, we can see exactly what is happening and can take your code, compile it, and see the results.

Comment: Hi PaulMcKenzie, the input is "3 R S P" but only the size of it will be used in computer.cpp. The size will be 7.

Comment: No, put that data into the program you posted, not as a description.  [See this](https://www.ideone.com/q5mxS9)

Comment: Alright, I have edited it for main.cpp.

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be modifying `rock` so it remains an empty string.

This constructs the `Computer` object with an empty `rock` string:

```
Computer computertest(rock, size);
```

This could potentially modify `rock` but it doesn't because it is commented out:

```
/*computertest.Computerplayer();*/
```